# Spring boot @Query ignores @Table on view call

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a spring boot 2 application that works great with entities that are mapped to a table that is in a MariaDB. I now do a view call and I have mapped that entity to the view using the @Table(name="ViewExpiredAccounts") annotation and now when the method is called the table name is ignored. I have a JpaRepository with this method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT v FROM ViewExpiredAccounts v")
List<ViewExpiredAccount> expiredAccounts();
```

When I call this method I get an error:

```
Table 'view_expired_accounts' doesn't exist
```

The query SHOULD! translate the table name so that the eventual SQL query sent to MariaDB is: `SELECT * from ViewExpiredAccount` however it doesnt do that. Is this a bug in Spring??

Answer (score 0):

did you reset the [hibernate naming strategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-access.configure-hibernate-naming-strategy)?

if yes, the following property might help

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```